# is it graceful to use kill to exit the idle thread in thread poll?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

The implementation of exit the idle thread is as follows:

```
int tp_delete_thread(TpThreadPool *pTp) {
    unsigned idx;
    TpThreadInfo *pThi;
    TpThreadInfo tT;

    //current thread num can't < min thread num
    if (pTp->cur_th_num <= pTp->min_th_num)
        return -1;
    //all threads are busy
    pThi = (TpThreadInfo *) ts_queue_deq_data(pTp->idle_q);
    if(!pThi)
        return -1;

    //after deleting idle thread, current thread num -1
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pTp->tp_lock);
    pTp->cur_th_num--;
    /** swap this thread to the end, and free it! **/
    memcpy(&tT, pThi, sizeof(TpThreadInfo));
    memcpy(pThi, pTp->thread_info + pTp->cur_th_num, sizeof(TpThreadInfo));
    memcpy(pTp->thread_info + pTp->cur_th_num, &tT, sizeof(TpThreadInfo));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pTp->tp_lock);

    //kill the idle thread and free info struct
    kill((pid_t)tT.thread_id, SIGKILL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&tT.thread_lock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&tT.thread_cond);

    return 0;
}
```

For active threads, we can set a flag for the thread, when the thread finishes the job, it can gracefully exit itself.

However, the idle thread is often slept on a `pthread_cond_t` to get a job, thus we could not make it exit as active thread does. In the above code, the line `kill((pid_t)tT.thread_id, SIGKILL);` does the work to kill the idle thread. My question is is it graceful to kill the thread to make the idle thread exit? Is there any better ways to do so?

Comment: Terminating a thread is almost never safe unless the thread is trivial. If the heap is used at any point inside the thread at all, leaks can and will eventually occur. Or worse, if there is any synchronization in the thread, you can cause a lock-leak and deadlock yourself. You cannot stop non-cooperating threads safely, only entire processes. The thread must end from inside itself.

Comment: If it's idle, why can you not just queue it a job that tells it to exit?

Comment: What is `thread_id` and how is it initialised?

Answer (score 1):

It's not graceful, no.  If you kill the thread while it holds a mutex lock then that mutex will never be unlocked (unless you use a robust mutex) so you should at least send the kill with the mutex locked by the current thread, so you know the thread being killed doesn't have it.  Depending on what the thread being killed does that still might not be safe.

If the idle thread is waiting on a condition variable why can't you just signal it using the condition variable so it wakes up?